# Is $\mathbb{Q}(t):\mathbb{Q}$ a normal field extension?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I'm asked if $\mathbb{Q}(t):\mathbb{Q}$ a normal field extension. I'm using the fact that an extension L:K is normal if and only if L is the splitting field for some polynomial $f\in K[t]$. I want to say that this extension is not normal, but am not entirely sure why.

Comment: The definition of normal I am familiar with is that $L/K$ is normal if it is the splitting field of a *family* of polynomils. So for instance, $\overline{\Bbb Q}/\Bbb Q$ would be normal, even though it is not the splitting field of some polynomial $f\in\Bbb Q[x]$.

Comment: The definition of normal I am familiar with assumes that the extension is algebraic, which this one clearly isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: is the splitting field for $f \in K[t]$ finite over $K$? Is $\Bbb{Q}(x)$ finite over $\Bbb{Q}$?